# omniauth google_oauth2 the profile image is not present in the authhash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, user-profile

This is written in omniauth.rb an initializer.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2,ID,SECRET,
  {
  :approval_prompt => '',
  :scope => 'http://gdata.youtube.com,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
  }
```

### **The returned auth hash does not have IMAGE element in the "info", why?????????**

Replaced original info with x in the below HASH

```
*********************
--- !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
provider: google_oauth2
uid: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
info: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash
  name: xxxx xxx 
  email: xxxxxxxxxx 
  first_name: xxxxxx
  last_name: xxxxxxx 
credentials: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
  expires_at: 1365434778
  expires: true
extra: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  raw_info: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
    id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
    email: xxxxxxxxxx.xxx@gmail.com 
    verified_email: true
    name: xxxx xxxx 
    given_name: xxx 
    family_name: xxx 
    link: https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxx 
    gender: male
    locale: en
*********************
```

**I want the profile image, what am I doing wrong?**

Also tried,

{:scope => 'userinfo.email,userinfo.profile'}

Not working!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what that scope is doing, but I've just solved getting google info for myself.
Is that information the actual params sent to rails, or is it the saved user hash?

If it's not the actual params you get on login, you can use:

```
# sessions_controller.rb
raise env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml
```

That'll show you everything that google is sending you.

If it's the user and If you've followed [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth-revised?view=asciicast) like I was doing, then check that you've created a field to save the pics and that you've set the field to save the info from the hash. I did this:

```
# sessions_controller.rb
def create
  user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  user.image = env["omniauth.auth"]['info']['image']
  user.save
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
end
```

If that's not what you're needing, can you be more specific?